# Java Multithread time switching

Tags: java, multithreading

My knowledge of how multithreading works in Java on a low level is little. I understand that when you have two threads running, Java allocates "time chunks" to each thread for execution.

For example:

```
public void test()
{
    Thread testThread = new Thread(new TestThread());
    testThread.start();

    for (int i = 0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; ++i)
        System.out.print("a");
}

private class TestThread extends Thread
{
    public void run()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; ++i)
            System.out.print("b");
    }
}
```

would print out something like:
aaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbaaaaaa...
and NOT:
abababababababababababababababab.....


**My question is:** Is it possible to reduce the "time chunks" so we get something closer to:
aabbaaabbaabbaaabbaabbbaabbaabbbaabbaaa...


Why? I am attempting to write an apple push notification server (just for fun). When you write a request to the apple push notification service one or two things can happen:
1. If the request is valid, nothing will return.
2. If the request is invalid, it will return an error code and close the connection and any requests sent after the invalid request and before the connection closing are discarded.

Because reading a socket blocks until data is available to read (which may never happen if I don't write any invalid requests), I cannot simply read after every write to see if there was an error without setting a timeout of 200-500 milliseconds. If there we have one million requests to write (very possible) this timeout would add 55 - 138 HOURS and we could miss a returned error due to the short timeout which would cause requests to never be sent.

So I have two threads like my example above, one that is writing to the server and one that is reading waiting to see if an error is returned. Here's the problem: If request #4 is bad but we write #5-#10 before we read the error and the connection closes, requests #5-10 are discarded by the apple service. Therefor, once we know #4 is bad and we know the last request we wrote is #10, we need to re-queue #5-10 to be sent again.

The problem I have now is because of the large "time chucks", I am able to write requests #1-#400 before the read thread reads there is an error with #5 so #6-#400 are re-queued and sent again. Then the read thread reads there is an error with #21 so #22-#400 are re-queued and sent again... etc. Ideally the read thread would be able to read from the socket for every 5-10 requests written.

Source:

```
private Object readWriteLock = new Object();
private volatile int     lastWrittenIndex;
private volatile boolean doneWriting;
private List<PushNotificationRequest> pushNotificationRequestsResnedList = new ArrayList<PushNotificationRequest>();

public boolean write()
{
    // get the requests read list
    List<PushNotificationRequest> requests = getPushNotificationRequests(false);

    // as long as there are more notifications to write...
    while (requests.size() > 0)
    {
        lastWrittenIndex = -1;
        doneWriting = false;

        // create and start the read thread
        Thread readThread = new Thread(new ReadThread(), "APNS Reader");
        readThread.start();

        for (int i = 0; i < requests.size(); ++i)
        {
            PushNotificationRequest request = requests.get(i);

            // write
            boolean success = false;

            // attempt to send the notification a number of times
            for (int j = 0; j < MAX_NUM_PN_WRITE_ATTEMPTS; ++j)
            {
                synchronized (readWriteLock)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        // get the socket connection
                        SSLSocket socket = getAppleServiceSSLSockett();
                        OutputStream socketOutputStream = socket.getOutputStream();

                        socketOutputStream.write(request.binary);
                        socketOutputStream.flush();

                        success = true;
                        lastWrittenIndex = i;

                        break;
                    }
                    catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    catch (AppleServiceConnectionException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            if (!success)
                System.err.println("APNS Unable to send push notification:\n" + request);
        }

        // wait for some time so we can make sure the read thread can read everything
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(Config.APNS_READ_TIME_AFTER_DONE_WRITING_MILLISECONDS);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // let the read thread know we are done writing and close the connection so it unblocks
        doneWriting = true;
        closeAppleServiceSSLSockett();

        // wait for the read thread to return
        try
        {
            readThread.join();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        // clear the reading list
        requests.clear();

        // add the requests from the re-send to the list
        if (pushNotificationRequestsResnedList.size() > 0)
        {
            requests.addAll(pushNotificationRequestsResnedList);

            // clear the re-send list
            pushNotificationRequestsResnedList.clear();
        }
    }
}

private class ReadThread extends Thread
{
    public void run()
    {
        byte[] readBuffer = new byte[1024];
        int numBytesRead;
        int totalNumBytesRead;

        while (!doneWriting)
        {
            try
            {
                // get the socket connection
                SSLSocket socket = getAppleServiceSSLSockett();
                socket.setSoTimeout(Config.APNS_READ_TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS);

                InputStream socketInputStream = socket.getInputStream();

                // read (blocking)
                totalNumBytesRead = 0;
                while ((numBytesRead = socketInputStream.read(readBuffer)) != -1)
                    totalNumBytesRead += numBytesRead;

                // check for an error
                if (totalNumBytesRead > 0)
                {
                    synchronized (readWriteLock)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            PushNotificationResponse response = new PushNotificationResponse(readBuffer, 0);
                            System.err.println("APNS Read got response with id: " + response.identifier);

                            // find the request with the given identifier
                            int i;
                            for (i = lastWrittenIndex; i > -1; --i)
                            {
                                if (pushNotificationRequestsReadingList.get(i).identifier == response.identifier)
                                    break;
                            }


                            if (i == -1)
                            {
                                // something went wrong, we didn't find the identifier
                                System.err.println("APNS Read unable to find request with id: " + response.identifier);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                System.err.println("APNS Read " + response.getErrorMessage(pushNotificationRequestsReadingList.get(i)));

                                // add the requests between the bad request and the last written (included)
                                for (++i; i <= lastWrittenIndex; ++i)
                                    pushNotificationRequestsResnedList.add(pushNotificationRequestsReadingList.get(i));
                            }
                        }
                        catch (InvalidPushNotificationResponseException g)
                        {
                            g.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    // the socket will be closed, reopen it
                    try
                    {
                        reopenAppleServiceSSLSockett();
                    }
                    catch (AppleServiceConnectionException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (SocketException e)
            {
                // ignore a close, it is expected
                if (!e.getMessage().equals("Socket closed"))
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (AppleServiceConnectionException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While a thread is blocked on a socket read, the thread is idle and other threads can do their job. Why don't you simply have several threads writing messages and reading responses, synchronously, in parallel? Anyway, if you want to go your road, you have to synchronize the reader and writer threads by yourself.

Comment: you need to improve your parallel experience, [this](http://arashmd.blogspot.com/2013/06/java-threading.html) would help you

Comment: Are the readers/writers separate threads within the same process, or are they separate processes?  If the former then I would use a [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) instead of a socket

Comment: I feel that you are trying to solve your problem the wrong way.  Write a proper multi-threaded program and you won't have to worry about the thread scheduling details.  For example, you could have a writer thread and a reader thread, and the writer thread should signal to the reader thread when an error is detected.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using Thread.yield() to ask the thread scheduler to move to the next thread?

```
// using Thread.yield() MIGHT give you the results you want
for (int i = 0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; ++i)
{
    System.out.print("a");
    Thread.yield();
}
```

Keep in mind that thread scheduling is up to the underlying OS, so the above is just an educated guess - I haven't tried running it.  See [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/thread_yield.htm) for an example.

EDIT: [here](http://javaho.wordpress.com/2011/01/10/jvm-thread-scheduling-is-platform-dependent/) is some more info about how different platforms implement yield.

Comment: there is no any warranty to yield, it's kind of [untrustful guy](http://arashmd.blogspot.com/2013/06/java-threading.html#switch0)

Comment: I'm not claiming this to be a fool proof solution, but could you get it going by using: `Thread.sleep(10);`

If all you have is 2 threads, this would work. But I don't think you can scale this approach... as we have no control over which thread gets a priority within a queue. That's OS's business.

Answer (score 1):

It's not java, but the OS actually that schedules the time chunks for the threads. In a producer/consumer scenario you want to provide fairness on the producer side, so that one producer gives one output after all other have given their own. For this, you can have one thread that round robing over a couple of lazy producers. that is:

N producers expose a getNextThing() and 1 Consumer round robins over the producers and pipe the results to a list that you consume

Comment: Well, I think the JVM actually does the scheduling of the threads.. However, all of the threads scheduled must be run during the JVM's timeslice.

Comment: @Joel - no, OS does it in all JVM I have experience of.

Comment: In fact, there is no other sane way to do it, since the OS has control of all I/O, and so MUST be responsible for scheduling/dispatching all threads in all processes.

Comment: @Martin James Well, actually the JVM used to support both types.  Threads that were scheduled by the os and threads that were scheduled and run by the JVM itself.  However, that may no longer be supported, I am not sure.